# Accuracy of GpsLocation.Heading on Windows Mobile

Tags: vb.net, gps, windows-mobile, heading, windows-mobile-gps

I've been use `GpsLocation.Heading` to get the current direction/orientation of my device.

But it seems not accurate, where the value is either:

- keep changing with a huge difference even I just put the device on the table without moving it
- or the value didn't change even I move around and rotate the device.

means, it was very inconsistent and inaccurate.

As, I believe, from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee484992.aspx), `Heading` suppose to give me the value(in degrees) of where my device currently heading.

Does anybody know how to use it properly, or how to get the accurate value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This heading will only be accurate when you move.

Look for a magnetic field sensor (compass) (if any) in the device and then use that.

Comment: how can I grant access to this compass (or they call it magnetometer?) Seriously I've stuck on this for 1 week and I'm giving up on vb.net

Comment: Please read my answer: if there is a magnetometer inside the device. If so, you need help by the manufacturer of the device. They should be able to provide a SDK. If you have further questions tell the device model code and manufacturer.

Comment: Yes, I've read your answer, just have no idea how to manipulate the magnetometer. But if I have to contact the device manufacture, then thats probably the answer. Sorry, Im using [Honeywell Dolphin 6000 Scanphone](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-mobile-computer&cat=HSM&pid=Dolphin6000)

Comment: AFAIK and from internet there is no accelerometer and no digital compass in this Dolphin 6000: http://www.ruggedandmobile.com/Product_Spec.aspx?PID=442. Even the official data sheet does no mention a digital compass. So you have the wrong device!

Comment: Oh God, thats too bad. thank you very much for your help. I've visited your blog and you have a lot of good stuff on Windows mobile development. Perhaps I can refer to your blog in my future works! Thanks